# Template engine with recursive template support

Tags: python, ruby, template-engine

Template engine can be used in code generation. The following is an example of Ruby ERB template script:

```
<ul><% for @item in @shopping_list %><li><%= @item %></li><% end %></ul>
```

But, my code generation requirement is more than simple variable expansion or for loop. I need recursive code generation capability, in other words, i need a python or ruby template engine with recursive template support. Could someone recommend such a template engine for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you should declare `item` as a local variable and not an instance variable. That is, `item` instead of `@item`.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby ERB template system used as default in Rails do support recursive templates. Here is an example.

*app/views/controller1/action1.html.erb*:

```
Factorial of <%= @n %> equals to <%= render "factorial", :n => @n %>
```

*app/views/controller1/_factorial.html.erb*:

```
<% if n == 1 %>
  1
<% else %>
  <%= n %> * <%= render "factorial", :n => n - 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
Factorial of 10 equals to 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Comment: how does `render "factorial"` know which template to use? because i didn't see there's a template defined as "factorial".

Comment: It seems to be the Rails feature. "factorial" is a [partial](http://ionrails.com/2009/08/08/rails-partial-templates/). `render` Rails function takes care of finding appropriate partial by its name. More precisely, when you pass "factorial" as the first parameter, `render` tries to find a file named "_factorial.html.erb" in app/views/controller1 and app/views/application. I didn't try to achieve this without Rails, but I suppose it's possible.